# Why is the size of the array longer than the elements within the brackets?

Tags: arrays, sorting

I was working on understanding sorting and ran into this problem. When I print the size of the `array[]` I get 32. Why is it 32 and not 8? Also when I print each element why are the numbers sorted at the end of the array(from array[24] and onwards?).
I also tried with

```
int array[8]= {6,3,8,5,2,7,4,1};
```

but it does not change anything.

Thank you for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[]= {6,3,8,5,2,7,4,1};

int main ()
{   
    printf("si of array %lu \n", sizeof(array));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
    {
         for (int  j = i+1; j < sizeof(array); j++)
    {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("sizee of array %lu \n", sizeof(array));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
    {
        printf("array[%i] = %d \n", i ,array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(array)` will return the size of array in bytes and since each integer is 4 bytes, that's why you are getting the size as 32 bytes(8 * 4 bytes) for 8 elements.

To get the number of elements in the array you should use:

```
size_t n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
```

Now if you use the above size then your sorting should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! makes sense